# How to play an audio file stored within the data folder of my app?

Tags: java, android

I'm currently using this piece of code -

```
fileName = recordings.get(position);
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        File file1 = new File(file.getAbsolutePath()+"/"+fileName);
        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file1), "audio/*");
        startActivity(intent);
```

But I get a toast from Google play music saying  "couldn't play the track you requested"

Comment: You have to show what `file` is and how you initialised it of course. We have to know where that file resides.

Comment: They are audio files of 5 different formats - MP3, FLAC, WAV, AAC and WMA. They reside in my app's data folder which is inaccessible, unless the phone is rooted.

Comment: Only the app internal data folder is not accessable for other apps. So you know already why you get that message. What do you want to know then?

Comment: But my app can surely access it's own data folder, right? and it is, because in the logs I get the filename with the path. The problem is not being able to play the file.

Comment: Yes your app can acces its own private internal memory. But other apps can not. So don't put your audio files there if other apps have to play them. Maybe it's possible with a content provider. But i cannot help you with that.

Comment: Ah, right. But I do not want the files to accessed by anyone, because I cannot let them be renamed or modified in anyway. Is there a way to make this folder hidden, and yet accessible by the Google Play Music app?

Comment: Which folder should be made hidden?

Comment: I plan on saving my audio files in a folder that is accessible by Google Play Music, but inaccessible through File Managers, so that no one can modify the file names. Is that possible?

Comment: Don't think so. Every file explorer can handle hidden folders.

Comment: Thank you. If you post the 5th comment as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes your app can acces its own private internal memory. But other apps can not. So don't put your audio files there if other apps have to play them.

Maybe it's possible with a content provider.